# Debug error in empty Swift 2 iOS Playground

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift2

I've just started out with Swift 2. By entering nothing (just leaving the default "import UIKit") still 3 errors show up in the debug area:

```
Sep 25 00:02:53  MyPlayground[1938] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 25 00:02:53  MyPlayground[1938] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Sep 25 00:02:53  MyPlayground[1938] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Please tell me what these mean, why they show up and how can I remove/correct them?

Comment: I am getting those too.  I think it is a playground bug

Comment: Okay so I guess than these are just temporary. In that case can I clear my Debug area somehow before printing to it or I should live with that?

Comment: Yeah.  They are annoying aren't they

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: Problem gone since iOS 9.2